# Deleting Row of Table based on div id using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Really need your help.

I have a table that can dynamically add and delete row. But the problem is I want to delete the row of the table based on div id. I mean, on one column for every row of table i have div id which are auto increment. Then, I want to delete the row based on the div id. Is that possible?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific. Are you using a specific framework? What have you tried? Could we get some code samples?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this really easy with jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/KWPWr/1/

```
$('#d2').closest('tr').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

```
$('#row-id').closest('tr').fadeOut(200, function() { $(this).remove(); });
```

The above will first select the div, then find the table row it exists in, fades it out and the removes it.

Answer (score 0):

If your table looks like this:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="01"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="02"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You can use `document.getElementById(DIVID).parentNode.parentNode` to access the `<tr>` Element.

Comment: This will work fine, but I'd recommend a safer solution to finding the tr. Use a loop to get the keep getting to the current parent until tagtype is tr.

Comment: what is the result of "document.getElementById(DIVID).parentNode.parentNode"? Position of the row or what?